# Get random element from array not more than once in a row

Tags: javascript, arrays

Ive written this function which shows a random item from the array, and then tried to add a bit where it won't pick the same thing twice but now the text doesnt even show.

EDIT Thanks Pointy and Jonas W for spotting that. Working now

```
var lyrics = function(){
var olditem = document.getElementById("space").innerHTML
var item = space[Math.floor(Math.random() * space.length)];
while (olditem === item) {
    item = space[Math.floor(Math.random() * space.length)];
}
if (olditem !== item) {
    document.getElementById("space").innerHTML = item;      
}};
```

Comment: Check the browser's developer console for the syntax error in your code.

Comment: While else is invalid...

Comment: Wow I totally forgot that you can't have an else in a while loop

Comment: Have a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Daniel-Hug/74e4f1ea6d7067f0283b). Specifically the Loop Random function looks like what your looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it exits the while loop, there is an implied `else` already there.
So I believe your `else` is causing it not to print. 
If you just remove that, it should be fine.

```
    var lyrics = function(){
        var olditem = document.getElementById("space").innerHTML
        var item = space[Math.floor(Math.random() * space.length)];
        while (olditem === item) {
            var item = space[Math.floor(Math.random() * space.length)];
        }
        document.getElementById("space").innerHTML = item;
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you do this

```
function lyrics(){
 var item = Math.floor(Math.random() * space.length);
 document.getElementById("space").innerHTML=space.splice(item,1)[0];
 }
```

That removes the item from the array, so it cant be used again...

Comment: have you tried to run it?

Comment: @Igor thanks for reminding me that splice returns an array...

Comment: I don't think that OP wanted to modify `space` array, and the assignment is still wrong

Comment: @Igor : now i dont know what you mean...

Comment: @igor 1 item != the first. Position is item wich is random...

Answer (score 0):

```
var lyrics = function() {
    var olditem = document.getElementById("space").innerHTML;

    var item = space[Math.floor(Math.random() * space.length)];


    while (olditem === item) {
        item = space[Math.floor(Math.random() * space.length)];
    }

    document.getElementById("space").innerHTML = item;
};
```

Comment: Doesnt make sense to add another if + return at the end is senseless

Comment: you are right about this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can shuffle the array, then take items by order.
Shuffle function taken from here: [How can I shuffle an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array)

```js
var data = [
  'one',
  'two', 
  'three',
  'four',
  'five'
]

function shuffle(a) {
    var j, x, i;
    for (i = a.length; i; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
        x = a[i - 1];
        a[i - 1] = a[j];
        a[j] = x;
    }
}

var pos = 0;
shuffle(data);

var lyrics = function(){
    pos++;
    if (pos == data.length) {
      pos = 0;
      shuffle(data);
    }
    return data[pos];
}


console.log(lyrics());
console.log(lyrics());
console.log(lyrics());
```